# Mysql SAVEPOINT in PHPUnit Tests

Tags: php, mysql, phpunit

I'm having a problem when running my PHPUnit test of creating a new profile, my code doesnt allow duplicate of profile_name and so i have to change it manually everytime i run a test. I actually thought of creating a SAVEPOINT before my tests runs and Then ROLLBACK at the end of the test..

My code for setting up the code is:

> require_once "PHPUnit/Extensions/Database/TestCase.php"

```
protected function getDatabaseTester()
{
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', 'password');
  $conn = new PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DB_DefaultDatabaseConnection($pdo, 'test');
}

public function testMyTestCase()
{
  $query = mysql_query(SAVEPOINT last_record);
  *my testing methods thats works fine*
  $query = mysql_query(ROLLBACK last_record);
}
```

What can i be doing wrong because it doesnt work at all..

Thanks
D~~~

Comment: What do you mean, "doesn't work"? What it should be doing? What is it doing instead? Any errors? Warnings?

Comment: Hi Piskvor,

It should ROLLBACK to the previous database state before the transaction was made, at the moment it just give me the validation error that the profile_name exists..there are no warnings its only the validation error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could provide more information with :

```
 echo mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error(). "\n";
 $query = mysql_query("ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT last_record");
```